# Sql Server double subquery

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I have a table which is kinda like an historic table... so I have data like this

`idA numberMov FinalDate`   
`1     10      20090209`     
`2     14      20090304`    
`1     12      20090304`    
`3     54      20080508`    
`4     42        20090510`   
`...   ...     ....`

I need to retrieve the numberMov based on the newest finalDate from each idA so I use this

`select a.numberMov from (select idA, max(finalDate) maxDate from table1 group by idA) as b inner join table1 a on a.idA=b.idA and a.finalDate = b.maxDate`

Now I have another query like this

`select m fields from n tables where n5.numberMov in ("insert first query here")`

I feel like there is a better solution but can't think of any, I really dont like having two subqueries in there.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not enough information to test it myself but something like this might work.

```
select m fields
from a inner join
 (select numberMov,
  max(FinalDate) as maxDate
 from a
 group by numberMov) b 
  on a.numberMov = b.numberMov
  and a.FinalDate = b.maxDate inner join
 n tables on a.numberMov = n.numberMov
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which edition of SQL server, but this will work in SQL 2005+

```
;WITH rankCTE
AS
(
    SELECT idA
           ,numberMov
           ,FinalDate
           ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY idA
                               ORDER BY FinalDate DESC
                              ) AS rn
    FROM table1
)
,latestCTE
AS 
(
    SELECT idA
           ,numberMov
           ,FinalDate
    FROM rankCTE
    WHERE rn = 1
)
SELECT m fields 
FROM n tables 
WHERE n5.numberMov IN (SELECT numberMov FROM latestCTE)
```